# How do I pass in values manually for swagger api calling in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "description" : "Project API Swagger Documentation",
    "version" : "20-30",
    "title" : "Project API Swagger Documentation",
    "termsOfService" : "",
    "contact" : { }
  },
  "host" : "localhost:9080",
  "basePath" : "/home/project/rest",
  "schemes" : [ "http" ],
  "paths" : {
        "/kmh/dashboardAttributes" : {
          "get" : {
            "tags" : [ "kmh" ],
            "summary" : "Get kmhDashboard Attributes",
            "description" : "Returns attributes for kmh Dashboard",
            "produces" : [ "application/json" ],
            "parameters" : [ {
              "name" : "iv-user",
              "in" : "header",
              "description" : "ID of the user",
              "required" : true,
              "type" : "string"
            } ],
```

So basically I have a swagger API which references the ID of the user in the header automatically.
How do I manually pass in an ID of the user for the API? I am quite confused as to how can I pass in the values in angular so that when calling the API, I am passing in the correct parameters for the api.

** What do I have to do to pass the value in the get request to the api and for the api to take the value from the get request? ** Edit

I am using angular 2.

In my service in angular.

```
    public getID() : Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} ); // ... Set content type to JSON      
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true }); // Create a request option

        return this.http.get('/api/services/v1/home/project/kmh/dashboardAttributes' , options ) // ...using get request
            .map(this.extractData)
           .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Swagger documentation it states

```yaml
"parameters" : [ {
  "name" : "iv-user",
  "in" : "header",
```

So in your header variable, you must add

```js
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', "iv-user": "{{my-username}}" }); // ... Set content type to JSON
```

And replace `{{my-username}}` by the username of your user.

I also suggest you to switch from `Headers` (Fetch API) to [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders) (Angular).

`Headers` is a class from the Fetch API (not from Angular). I'm not sure it will work correctly with the `HttpClient` of Angular. You do not need `import` to use Headers. Unlike `HttpHeaders` which needs `@angular/common/http` import and is designed to work with the `HttpClient` of Angular.

Comment: Hi @Marco

Just to clarify

I realised the header has this object

```
    {
     "priorityIvGroup":"worker-ID",
     "loginType":"WORKER ID",
     "p2-homepage":"worker-id",
     "isLoggedIn":true,
     "ivUser":"P88881",
     "ivGroups":["WORKER_ID","WORKER"],
     "nric":"P88881"
    }

```
So do i still put iv-user or ivUser ?

Also why the switch to httpHeaders?

Comment: You need to follow the documentation. It it states `"name" : "iv-user"` you need to label it `iv-user`, if it states anything else you must do as indicated. I will clarify the `Headers`/`HttpHeaders` problem.

Comment: Hi Marco do i need to { { } } ?
If i am taking a parameter ID: string

can I just do "iv-user": ID  ?

Comment: You don't need `{{}}`, just put the ID

Comment: i got an "Unexpected token < in json at position 0" .

Comment: Sorry marco, how do I use options with HttpHeaders?
I am using 
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, withCredentials: true });

by httpHeaders isn't assignable to Headers. I think the FetchApi has an issue with passing the value. which resulted in the unexpected token

Comment: Can you update completely the code in your question ?